# Ember: correct way to render background image in an element

Tags: ember.js

This is the `html`:

```
<div style="background-image: url({{person.picture}});"></div>
```

This renders all good, but keep receiving this warning:

> warn.js:48 WARNING: Binding style attributes may introduce cross-site
>   scripting vulnerabilities; please ensure that values being bound are
>   properly escaped. For more information, including how to disable this
>   warning, see
>   https://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_binding-style-attributes.
>   Style affected: "background-image:
>   url(https://www.userImage.com/cuautemok.png);"

Tried:

```
<div style=background-image: url({{person.picture}});></div>

<div style="background-image: url('{{person.picture}}');"></div>

<div style="background-image: url("{{person.picture}}");"></div>
```

and many more... No luck yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct way it to bind `style`:

```
<div style={{style}}></div>
```

and then use a computed property to produce a safestring:

```
import { htmlSafe } from '@ember/string';

...
style: computed('person.picture', {
  get() {
    return htmlSafe(`background-image: url(${get(this, 'person.picture')});`);
  }
}),
```

however be sure you understand what this does. if `person.picture` does contain anything that may me manipulated by the user you open a XSS attack!

another solution could be to use [`ember-css-properties`](https://github.com/rtablada/ember-css-properties)